# iOS 10 UIViewController presented with Over Current Context is not rotating when device orientation is changed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation, uimodalpresentationstyle

I've setup the Presentation type to Over Current Context in Storyboard.

When the segue is called the new UIViewController appears correctly.

However when the device orientation changes the new UIViewController does not rotate even though its parent UIViewController does.

Searching around on StackOverflow I don't see any modern (iOS 9 and higher) references to this only hacks for dealing with iOS 6 / 7.

If set in code then the UIModalPresentationStyle would be set to overCurrentContext.